# How spark creates stages and divides them into small tasks for spark data stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

When I am creating data stream in spark for incoming data from kafka then I am getting following warning -
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 1 contains a task of very large size (1057 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.

So I think I need to increase task size,So can we resolve this issue by increasing no of partitions for a RDD? And How a stage is divided into small tasks and how we can configure the size of these tasks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> So can we resolve this issue by increasing no of partitions for a RDD?

Not at all. Task size is amount of data that is send to the exectuor. This includes function definition, and serialized closure. Modifying splits won't help you here.

In general this warning is not critical and I wouldn't worry to much, but it is a hint you should take another look at your code:

- Do you reference large objects with actions / transformations? If yes, consider using broadcast variables.
- Are you sure you send only things you expect to send, not enclosing scope (like large objects). If the problem is here work on the structure of your code.